# I am trying to select one attribute with same id

Tags: css, selenium, xpath

[image]

I am trying to select one attribute which is having same id's. I used nth-of-type , but that didn't help. So, could someone please help me, I am adding screenshot for reference.

Comment: IDs are unique or they should be. please use classes for repeating css

Comment: Yes, you'll create all kinds of issues for yourself if you have repeating IDs. Classes or data- attributes are better for this. Also note nth-of-type applies only to tags (e.g. <a>, <p>, <div>), it does not apply to other selectors such as #id or .class.

Comment: Stack Overflow offers a nice way to include code in posts. Please add the relevant piece of code directly in your question.

Answer (score 1):

for first element CSS

```
#permit_1>#permit_details
```

For second element

```
#permit_2>#permit_details
```

Comment: @NagarajS. you should accept the answer if it works. not only for this but in future for all the answers as well. this helps other people who stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
(//div[@id='permit_details'])[1]
```

change the array to 1 or 2 as required

Comment: thats may be because we haven't use permit_1 id..  (//div[@id='permit_1']//div[@id='permit_details'])[1] should work